# Set classpath for playframework

Tags: java, playframework-2.1

I am running a project using `$ activator "run 8081"`. In the application, I try to read an xml file using the following command:

```
resource = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(filePath)
```

The problem is that the resource is `null`. After debuging, I noticed that the running `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getURLs()` returns a single jar file. Which means that the above code is trying to load `filePath` from inside this jar file.

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this problem and load the `filePath`? Note that I have to keep the `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(filePath)` as is, but I can change the value of `filePath` and environment variables, etc.

---

**EDIT:**

How do I set the classpath for `activator` when I run it in dev mode: `$ activator "run 8081"`?

Answering this can help answer my original question.

Comment: What the goal at first?

Comment: The goal is to get a resource using ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(filePath). At the moment, I get null.

Comment: there is no need to, ressources are accessible from `getClass.getResourceX`

Comment: Let me change the question then.

Comment: There is still no need. The dependencies are managed by the build, the ressources are available according the source layout (either `conf` or in `src`)

Comment: Yeah. It should be like that, but it is not! If I place the files in conf, it does not find them. If I place them in "./target/scala-2.10/classes", it finds them. Therefore, I think that I need to somehow give activator the list of my classpaths